# Curve that describes all possible points C, where points A and B and the ratio of their distances to C are known

Tags: geometry

I have known points A and B on a 2D plane, and I know the ratio of the distance between A to C and B to C, but not the actual distances. How can I find the equation for the curve that represents all the possible coordinates of point C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=(x_a,y_a), B=(x_b,y_b),$ and $C=(x_c,y_c)$. The distance from $A$ to $C$ is
$$\sqrt{(x_a-x_c)^2+(y_a-y_c)^2}$$
And the distance from $B$ to $C$ is
$$\sqrt{(x_b-x_c)^2+(y_b-y_c)^2}$$
If the ratio of $\frac{AC}{BC}=d$, then:
$$d=\frac{\sqrt{(x_a-x_c)^2+(y_a-y_c)^2}}{\sqrt{(x_b-x_c)^2+(y_b-y_c)^2}}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I believe I can, thanks for the help!